# Is $\lim_{S\rightarrow T} \frac{1}{S-T} ( \frac{B(t,T)}{B(t,S)} - 1) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln B(t,T)$?

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance

$B(t,X)$ is the price at time $t$ of a zero coupon bond say at time $X$, time $S>T$.

When I try to compare it to the standard definition from textbooks and wikipedia I just can't make the connection.

Is  $\lim_{S\rightarrow T} \frac{1}{S-T} ( \frac{B(t,T)}{B(t,S)} - 1) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln B(t,T)$?

I have had the question unfinished in my browser for a week now, the only thinkg I can think of is  $\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \, dx = \ln(f(x))$ so the left hand side should look like the ratio of a function and its derivative.

$$\lim_{S\rightarrow T} \frac{1}{S-T} \bigg( \frac{B(t,T)}{B(t,S)} - 1\bigg) = 
\lim_{S\rightarrow T} \frac{1}{S-T} \bigg( \frac{B(t,T) - B(t,S)}{B(t,S)}\bigg)$$ $$ =
\lim_{S\rightarrow T} \frac{B(t,T) - B(t,S)}{S-T} \cdot \frac{1}{B(t,S)}
=-\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln B(t,T)$$

OK finally I think this is there? So the first term is the derivative at $T$ ? Please let me know of any errors (or if I am way out).

Comment: When you write 3\text{ln} B you see $3\text{ln}B$, but if you write the standard 3\ln B you see $3\ln B$, with proper spacing.  I changed it.  ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, I will try to remember that.